# Morris.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, html, graph, morris.js

I am new to php and javascript and i am working on a project where i need to implement the graph in my webpage but i am getting this error morris.min.js:6 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` and I am unable to find the solution

```
html code
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/AdminDashboard.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">2 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>3 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>4 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body><div class="bookingsGraph">
<div id="chart">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'chart',
        data: [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
        xkey: 'date',
        ykey: ['bookings'],
        labels: ['Bookings'],
        // hideHover: 'auto',
        // stacked: true

    });
</script>
```

php code

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "movietime");
$query = "SELECT COUNT(BookingId),BookingDate
FROM bookings
WHERE BookingDate='2019/12/13'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

  $chart_data .= "{ date:'".$row["BookingDate"]."', bookings:".$row["COUNT(BookingId)"]."}, ";
}
 $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
```

complete errror

```
morris.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at c.<anonymous> (morris.min.js:6:4567)
    at c.<anonymous> (morris.min.js:6:4834)
    at d.setData (morris.min.js:6:4865)
    at c.d [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6:1739)
    at new c (morris.min.js:6:13513)
    at Object.c [as Line] (morris.min.js:6:13534)
    at AdminDashboard.php:114:12
```

I have tried

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'chart',
    data: [{date:'2019/12/13',bookings:'6'}],
    xkey: 'date',
    ykey: ['bookings'],
    labels: ['Bookings'],
    // hideHover: 'auto',
    // stacked: true

});
```

Comment: Don't write your own JSON... -> `json_encode()`

Comment: If you encounter a problem in a minified script then reproduce the problem with the non-minified version. Makes it so much easier for you/us to find and understand the code that throws the error.

Comment: I get a different error with your setup: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk46xvgo/

Comment: What do you get when you `echo $chart_data`? Also, what do you get when you try to validate the output of `echo $chart_data` with something like [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com)? Your Morris.js setup seems fine, if I work with pregenerated data: https://jsfiddle.net/n4auzmov/

Comment: dont know why but when i changed my code to the given code here  jsfiddle.net/Lk46xvgo – it worked thank you for the help